# Social links reference and CSS design

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm trying to figure out, how to fix the social links design.

GitHub and Spotify size is different, and seems like Blogger icon is not in reference:

[image]

According [How To Create Social Media Buttons - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_social_media_buttons) librarie reference:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

HTML specific list, also must be updated with other social network links:

```
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-soundcloud"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-github"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-spotify"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-blogger"></a>
```

and CSS:

```
.fa {
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  .fa:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  .fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .fa-twitter {
    background: #55ACEE;
    color: white;
  }
   
  .fa-linkedin {
    background: #007bb5;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .fa-youtube {
    background: #bb0000;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .fa-instagram {
    background: #125688;
    color: white;
  }
  
 .fa-soundcloud {
    background: #ff5500;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .fa-reddit {
    background: #ff5700;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-github {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .fa-spotify {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #1DB954;
  }

 .fa-blogger {
    background:  #fc4f08;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 }
```

**edit 1:**

Blogger icon appears with 6.2.0 version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
```

but for some reason, the same code from [@Cervus camelopardalis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10347145/cervus-camelopardalis) answer looks different in my browser, and GitHub and Spotify icons are still smaller than other icons as in the answer snippet too:

[image]

**edit 2:**

With the edit in `CSS`:

```
.fa-brands {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center !important; 
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

but GitHub and Spotify icons are a smaller then others:

[image]

and if I use `class="fa-brands fa-facebook` instead `class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f` than the Facebook icon is also small like GitHub and Spotify icons:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Font Awesome `v4.7.0` doesn't support the Blogger icon.

[image: No support]

Use Font Awesome `v6.2.0`.

See the snippet below.

```css
.fa-brands {
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook-f {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.fa-youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}

.fa-soundcloud {
  background: #ff5500;
  color: white;
}

.fa-reddit {
  background: #ff5700;
  color: white;
}

.fa-github {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.fa-spotify {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1DB954;
}

.fa-blogger {
  background: #fc4f08;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-soundcloud"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-github"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-spotify"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa-brands fa-blogger"></a>
```

Comment: Hello, I've edited the question according to your answer

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Blogger icon appears with 6.2.0 version, please check edit 2, I got the same result with Chrome and Mozzila, your answer snippet also shows GitHub and Spotify icons smaller than others.